# How do I use ListPlot with error bars properly

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I'm trying to make a ListPlot with error bars: In this example I want one data point at x = 3, y = 1 and symmetric error bars of magnitude 0.5.
This is the code I'm using

```
    DataA = {3, Around[1, 0.5]};
    ListPlot[DataA]
```

However the data point and the error bar end up at x = 2 as you can see in the picture.[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: `ListPlot` takes a list of points as input, not a single point. The input list may contain only one point, but it must be a list nevetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a `PlotRange -> All` in your `ListPlot`, you will see what's happening more clearly:

```
ListPlot[DataA, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot with PlotRange -> All]

Notice that point without error bars at `{1, 3}`? `ListPlot` is actually interpreting your `DataA` list *not* as a single point with abscissa 3 and ordinate 1, but as a *list of two points* without an explicit abscissa, thereby plotting them with assumed abscissae of $1$ and $2$, respectively, according to the order in which they present themselves in your list.

---

To do what you want, wrap your point in a further set of braces, giving a single-element list of tuples:

```
newdata = {{3, Around[1, 0.5]}};
ListPlot[newdata, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot of the correctly specified list]

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Comment: @camileri I'm glad it helped!